# iCloud Drive set to "Optimise Mac storage" but Mac is running out of hard disk space

Tags: icloud, backup, storage

My setup is:

- Macbook Air 13 inch 2017 -  121gb flash storage
- Running Catalina 10.15.7
- 2 TB iCloud account
- Mac is Set to Optimised Mac Storage

I'm running out of hard disk space and only have 6gb remaining. I thought iCloud would 'demote' unused files to iCloud to free up disk space on Mac as required.

When trying to upgrade to Monteray it times out as there is insufficient space ... but it doesn't purge older files to iCloud.